# Adding arrows to rectangles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, decorations, shapes

Is it possible to decorate rectangles with arrows? I used:

```
\node [draw,rectangle,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm](r){};
```

But then it is really difficult to line up an edge so that it's level with the edge of the rectangle, is there an easier way? I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can find some inspiration here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172288/complex-dynamically-sized-tikz-diagram

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Answer (score 4):

Your rectangle is a `node`. Hence you can place an arrow shaped node at its anchors like `south` and `east`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
myarrow/.style={
  draw,thick,
  single arrow,
  text width=1cm,
  fill=white
  },
}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [draw,rectangle,minimum size=4cm](r){};
   \node[myarrow,rotate=90] at (r.east){};
   \node[myarrow] at (r.south){};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

For modifying the shape of the arrow, you may refer to `pgfmanual` page 725, section 67.5, under shape `single arrow`.

Comment: Using the calc library you can also locate between anchors like ($(r.south west)!0.25!(r.south east)$)

Answer (score 3):

And here's a simple [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) approach.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

ad_phi = 1/2;
ad_rho = 7/8;

% return the path of an arrow scaled to size "s" at time "t" on path "p"
vardef arrow_decor(expr s, t, p) = 
  save a; path a;
  a = ((1,0) -- (0,ad_rho) -- (0,ad_phi) -- (-1,ad_phi) 
      -- (-1,-ad_phi) -- (0,-ad_phi) -- (0,-ad_rho) -- cycle) 
      scaled 1/2 s
      rotated angle direction t of p 
      shifted point t of p;
  unfill a;
  a
  enddef;

beginfig(1);
path R; 
R = unitsquare xscaled 55 yscaled 34;
draw R; 
for t = 1/2 step 1 until 4:
  draw arrow_decor(8, t, R);
endfor
endfig;
end.
```

Adjust `ad_rho` and `ad_phi` to control the shape of the arrow. Or just change the definition of `a` in the macro to suit.